# How to give differents directions of bullets on one array?

Tags: actionscript-3

im very new on javascript, i was doing a ship gaming that you have to kill some asteroids, and when you take some differents of "objects" on the screen we expand our number of bullets. Okey, going to the point i could get 3 bullets on the screen when you take diffirents objects, but now i want to give 2 of that 3 bullets of the array different directions. When i tried, i have the problem that i give the 3 bullets the same direction, i know why but im for at least 5hrs trying to fix this and i cant.

Im programming on Flash Builder 4.7 with different classes, i ll give the code of the array who is in the main, and the bullet class so as the hero class too.

Main Array

```
public function evUpdateBullet():void//here execute update of my class Bullets
    {
        var i:int;
        for(i=myBullets.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if(myBullets != null) //to be ?
            {
                if(myBullets[i].isDestroyed) //is destroyed Bullets?
                {
                    myBullets[i] = null;
                    myBullets.splice(i, 1); //deleted elements.
                }else
                {

                    myBullets[i].evUpdate();





                }
            }
        }
    }
```

here i push the array and create the bullet, remember myBullets is the name of the array.

```
public function evShoot(posX:int, posY:int):void//here create the bullet and push in the array
    {
        attack1 = new Bullet;
        attack1.Spawn(posX, posY);
        myBullets.push(attack1);
```

}

here i show the Hero code, where i define the position of the bullet is going to spawn on the screen.

```
if (isPressing_Shoot && !isDestroyed)// Here execute the event shoot without power
        {
            Main.instace.evShoot(model.x, model.y);


            isPressing_Shoot = false;
            canShoot = false;

        }


        evDestroyed();
    }
```

here is the code from Bullet class

first the spawn

```
public function Spawn(posX:int, posY:int):void
    {
        isDestroyed = false;//first parameter of my bullet

        model = new MCbullet;
        Main.layer1.addChild(model);//painting the hero in the stage
        model.x = posX;//position in the stage wiht the hero
        model.y = posY;
        model.tigger.visible = false;

    }
```

then the Update

```
public function evUpdate():void//here conect with update general
    {
        if (model != null)//to be?
        {

            model.y -= 12;//move of my bullet
            //model.x -= 12;





            if (model.y <= 0 )
            {
                evDestroyed();
            }
        }

    }
```

in this update i set the movement of y, so i can shoot vertically, but.. when i try to add an x.move, i do for the all array, so i want to know how i can give different move, for differents bullets of the same array.

Comment: What does being new to JavaScript have anything to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the array elements.  There are a few ways to do this, but the one I'm most accustomed to using would be the `for` loop.  It looks like this:

```
// loop through myBullets array to update 
// each x and y position dependent on unique 
// property value _xSpeed and _ySpeed.
for (var i:int = 0; i < myBullets.length; i++) 
{
    myBullets[i].x += myBullets[i]._xSpeed;
    myBullets[i].y += myBullets[i]._ySpeed;
}
```

Obviously, you will need the `_xSpeed` and `_ySpeed` properties of the array elements to be set to dynamic values.  You would first need to give the bullet class these properties and then set their values when you instantiate the bullets.  That might look something like this:

```
function makeBullet():void{
    var b:Bullet = new Bullet();
    b.x = hero.x;
    b.y = hero.y;
    b._xSpeed = hero._xSpeed; // or put here whatever makes sense for assigning the right value in your application
```

And in your bullet class constructor, before the `function` but inside the `class` brackets, add the property:

```
var _xSpeed:Number = 0;
var _ySpeed:Number = 0;
```

Basically this is allowing each bullet to hold it's own special property that is independent of any other instance of the class.

I hope that helps.